What term am I missing from the Feynman diagram calculation?
I am trying to follow this paper on the magnetic moment of the electron (or muon). In the following $p$ is the momentum of the incoming electron, $p'$ that of the outgoing momentum and $k=p-p'$ is the momentum of the photon.
On page 3 it gives an expansion of the current in the matrix element in terms of the form factors (with $k=p-p')$:
$$\Gamma^\mu(p,p') = F_1(k^2)\gamma^\mu + i\frac{k_\nu}{m} \sigma^{\mu\nu}F_2(k^2) + ..\tag{2.5}$$
On page 11 it gives the one-loop form of this as (where the denominator contains no gamma matrices):
$$\Gamma^\mu|_{1-loop}(p,p') \propto \int \frac{\gamma^\rho (\not p + \not q + m_e)\gamma^\mu(\not p' + \not q + m_e) \gamma^\rho}{...}dq^4 $$
The problem is this expression contains no $\sigma^{\mu\nu}$ term. Using the Dirac matrix identities, $\gamma^\rho \not p \gamma^\mu \gamma^\rho = 4 p^\mu$ for example and terms with an odd number of $\gamma$ can not give $\sigma$.
But the whole point of the 1-loop calculation is to find the $F_2(k^2)$ term which the paper then goes on to calculate as $F_2(0)|_{1-loop}  =\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}$
I feel like I must be missing something, perhaps some missing terms to do with the incoming and out-going fermions?

You need to apply the Gordon identity, see e.g. chapters 62-63 in Srednicki.

... which is precisely "some missing terms to do with the incoming and out-going fermions."  Sandwiching between external spinors and using the on-shell Dirac equation $\not p u(p)=m_{e}u(p)$ lets you change between even and odd numbers of $\gamma$-matrices.

Yes that looks like what I was missing! (Was it me or did the paper not explain it too well?) The Srednicki book looks really good.
Feel free if anyone wants to do a more detailed explanation as an answer.

From the helpful comments I was able to find out the mistake. If $\Gamma^\mu(p,p')$ is the matrix element from the Feynman graph without external legs then the equation:
$$\Gamma^\mu(p,p') = F_1(k^2)\gamma^\mu + i\frac{k_\nu}{m} \sigma^{\mu\nu}F_2(k^2) + ..\tag{1}$$
is not true but it is true if we sandwich it like this (where $p^2=m^2$ and $p'^2=m^2$ and $k=p-p'$:
$$(\not p+m)\Gamma^\mu(p,p')(\not p'+m) = (\not p+m)\left(F_1(k^2)\gamma^\mu + i\frac{k_\nu}{m} \sigma^{\mu\nu}F_2(k^2) + ..\right)(\not p'+m) \tag{2}$$
which allows us to use the Gordon identity to transform terms in $\Gamma$ to those on the right. We could similarly sandwich it between on-shell fermion wave functions $\langle p|..|q\rangle$ which has the same effect.
Then following page 5 in the paper, we are able to get the term $F_2(k)$ with a projection matrix on the sandwiched term:
$$F_2(k) = Tr[ (\not p+m)\Gamma^\mu(p,p')(\not p'+m) \Delta^\mu_2(k)]$$
where $\Delta_2^\mu(k)$ is given in the paper, which is possible to derive by expanding out the RHS of (2).
